# Nginx - try_files with args and extension

Tags: file, nginx, configuration, http-proxy

I've got a frustration here.
Folders with static files:

```
 /home/jenkins/shared/images/
   /project
      /folder
        EyZvhbPJg.jpg
        EyZvhbPJg.jpg?width=200.jpg
```

Nginx backend configuration

```
    location @render {
       rewrite ^ /img$target break;
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
    }
```

Imagine a URL
/images/project/folder/EyZvhbPJg.jpg?width=200

The logic is.
If file is not found, @render location is triggered (which creates the files - resizes or does whatever's needed)

After that, the file is served by nginx. The problem is $args and $ext
Theoretically the target path for nginx should look like this:

```
 /home/jenkins/shared/images/$uri?$args$ext
```

There has to be a condition, if $args are not set, ?$args should ignored along with $ext

I tried many possible variations, but it does not seem to work. Something  gets broken in the middle. It turns out i cannot use if conditions and alias.

```
  location ~ ^\/images(?<target>.*\.(?<ext>jpg|png|jpeg|gif).*) {
       try_files /cached @render;
    }
    location ~ ^\/cached(?<target>.*(?<ext>\.jpg|\.png|\.jpeg|\.gif).*) {
         alias /home/jenkins/shared/images/$target?$args$ext;
    }

    location @render {
       rewrite ^ /img$target break;
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:3001;
    }
```

Any hints or directions are greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is $args and $ext?

Comment: Try using this as your target path, /home/jenkins/shared/$uri$is_args$args

Comment: $is_args might help! I will try it. Should i be sticking to alias? or use root instead?